Tensorflow: data augmentation with bounding box (for object detection) advice
I need advice for an effective data augmentation for an object detection problem (YOLO neural network) in tensorflow/keras.
My first option was to use tf keras layers, but not all of them support bounding boxes.
For example: keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize() supports bounding boxes but tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom() does not.
What would be your advice?
Additionally, I would be interested in the possibility of using ImageDataGenerator, is there a way to include my bounding boxes into the generator?
Thank you a lot.

You can use librairies such as Albumentations if you want to do data augmentation with bounding boxes.
